# Como comparar y unir dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo dos dataframes con una gran cantidad de datos( uno de mas de 10,000 y el otro de más de 300,000) donde el primero sería una base.

Ejemplo `DF_1`:

| COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B |
| --- | --- |
| CLAVE_1 | MENSAJE_1 |
| CLAVE_2 | MENSAJE_2 |

Ejemplo `DF_2`:

| DATO_A | DATO_B | DATO_C | DATO_D | COLUMN_A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DATO A_1 | DATO B_1 | DATO C_1 | DATO D_1 | CLAVE_1 |
| DATO A_2 | DATO B_2 | DATO C_2 | DATO D_2 | CLAVE_1 |
| DATO A_3 | DATO B_3 | DATO C_3 | DATO D_3 | CLAVE_1 |
| DATO A_4 | DATO B_4 | DATO C_4 | DATO D_4 | CLAVE_2 |
| DATO A_5 | DATO B_5 | DATO C_5 | DATO D_5 | CLAVE_3 |
| DATO A_6 | DATO B_6 | DATO C_6 | DATO D_6 | CLAVE_4 |
| DATO A_7 | DATO B_7 | DATO C_7 | DATO D_7 | CLAVE_2 |
| DATO A_8 | DATO B_8 | DATO C_8 | DATO D_8 | CLAVE_5 |
| DATO A_9 | DATO B_9 | DATO C_9 | DATO D_9 | CLAVE_2 |
| DATO A_10 | DATO B_10 | DATO C_10 | DATO D_10 | CLAVE_2 |
| DATO A_11 | DATO B_11 | DATO C_11 | DATO D_11 | CLAVE_1 |
| DATO A_12 | DATO B_12 | DATO C_12 | DATO D_12 | CLAVE_4 |

Necesito comparar la tabla `DF_1` y la `DF_2` y en una `DF_3` me quede la información con los datos que se comparten de la `Column_A` (`DF_1`) y adicionar `Column_B` (`DF_1`).

`DF_2` (algo así)

| DATO_A | DATO_B | DATO_C | DATO_D | COLUMN_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DATO A_1 | DATO B_1 | DATO C_1 | DATO D_1 | CLAVE_1 | MENSAJE_1 |
| DATO A_2 | DATO B_2 | DATO C_2 | DATO D_2 | CLAVE_1 | MENSAJE_1 |
| DATO A_3 | DATO B_3 | DATO C_3 | DATO D_3 | CLAVE_1 | MENSAJE_1 |
| DATO A_4 | DATO B_4 | DATO C_4 | DATO D_4 | CLAVE_2 | MENSAJE_2 |
| DATO A_7 | DATO B_7 | DATO C_7 | DATO D_7 | CLAVE_2 | MENSAJE_2 |
| DATO A_9 | DATO B_9 | DATO C_9 | DATO D_9 | CLAVE_2 | MENSAJE_2 |
| DATO A_10 | DATO B_10 | DATO C_10 | DATO D_10 | CLAVE_2 | MENSAJE_2 |
| DATO A_11 | DATO B_11 | DATO C_11 | DATO D_11 | CLAVE_1 | MENSAJE_1 |

Ya probe con:

```py
DF_2['COLUMN_A'] =ncdf.apply(lambda x: DF_1['COLUMN_A'] if DF_2['COLUMN_A'].isin(DF_1['COLUMN_A']).any() else None)
```

Y con:

```py
DF_3 = DF_2.merge(DF_1['COLUMN_A'], how="left")
```

Este me da la información que necesito pero sin la COLUMN_B.

Comment: para que me quede claro, el `output` filtra el segundo DF2 solo si tiene como mensaje uno existente en el DF1? el valor de column_A en df2 es `column A_1` o  es `clave_1`

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. No entiendo como se relacionan los datos de `COLUMN_A` de ambos data-frames si tienen valores distintos, ¿Podrías explicar más a detalle la manera de relacionarlos?

Comment: Tienen razón, el dato es CLAVE_1  en DF_2, hice la corrección en la pregunta, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya casi lo tienes, lo unico que tienes que modificar es:

```
DF_3 = DF_2.merge(DF_1['COLUMN_A'], how="left")
```

por

```
DF_3 = DF_2.merge(DF_1['COLUMN_A'], how="outer")
```

La explicacion es que `left` solo deja las llaves de la dataframe a la izquierda. `outer` permite conservar los datos de ambos dataframes y en los casos que no existe dato, la llena con None.

Saludos.